# Add column to table with data from another table

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a table that looks as follows:

```
Table1 <- data.frame(
    "Random" = c("A", "B", "C"), 
    "Genes" = c("Apple", "Candy", "Toothpaste"), 
    "Extra" = c("Up", "", "Down"), 
    "Desc" = c("Healthy,Red,Fruit", "Sweet,Cavities,Sugar,Fruity", "Minty,Dentist")
)
```

giving:

```
  Random      Genes Extra                       Desc
1      A      Apple    Up          Healthy,Red,Fruit
2      B      Candy       Sweet,Cavities,Sugar,Fruity
3      C Toothpaste  Down              Minty,Dentist
```

I have another table with Descriptions and want to add a columns with Genes. For instance Table2 would be:

```
Table2 <- data.frame(
    "Col1" = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 
    "Desc" = c("Sweet", "Sugar", "Dentist", "Red", "Fruit", "Fruity")
)
```

Giving:

```
  Col1    Desc
1    1   Sweet
2    2   Sugar
3    3 Dentist
4    4     Red
5    5   Fruit
6    6  Fruity
```

I want to add another column to Table2 named "Genes" that matches the "Desc" from both tables and adds the Genes from Table1 to get:

```
  Col1    Desc    Gene
1    1   Sweet    Candy
2    2   Sugar    Candy
3    3 Dentist    Toothpaste
4    4     Red    Apple
5    5   Fruit    Apple
6    6  Fruity    Candy
```

Comment: I had a good laugh at the value of `Toothpaste` for `Gene`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try `cSplit` from `splitstackshape` to split the 'Desc' column in "Table1" and convert the dataset from 'wide' to 'long' format.  The output will be a `data.table`.  We can use the `data.table` methods for setting the key column as 'Desc' (`setkey`), join with "Table2", and finally remove the columns that are not needed in the output either by selecting the columns or assigning (`:=`) the unwanted columns to NULL

```
library(splitstackshape)
setkey(cSplit(Table1, 'Desc', ',', 'long'),Desc)[Table2[2:1]][
                   ,c(5,4,2), with=FALSE]
#  Col1    Desc      Genes
#1:    1   Sweet      Candy
#2:    2   Sugar      Candy
#3:    3 Dentist Toothpaste
#4:    4     Red      Apple
#5:    5   Fruit      Apple
#6:    6  Fruity      Candy
```

Comment: Would this also need library(data.table)? Or is it loaded automatically by library(splitstackshape)?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a method in base R that uses an intermediate linking table:

```
# create an intermediate data.frame with all the key (Desc) / value (Gene) pairs
df  <-  NULL
for(i in seq(nrow(Table1)))
    df  <-  rbind(df,
                  data.frame(Gene =Table1$Genes[i],
                            Desc =strsplit(as.character(Table1$Desc)[i],',')[[1]]))
df 
#>         Gene     Desc
#> 1      Apple  Healthy
#> 2      Apple      Red
#> 3      Apple    Fruit
#> 4      Candy    Sweet
#> 5      Candy Cavities
#> 6      Candy    Sugar
#> 7      Candy   Fruity
#> 8 Toothpaste    Minty
#> 9 Toothpaste  Dentist
```

Now link to it in the usual way:

```
Table2$Gene  <-  df$Gene[match(Table2$Desc,df$Desc)]
```

Answer (score 4):

If we can get a key lookup into a named list or 2 vectors (e.g., 2 column data frame) we can use the `%l%` function int he *qdapTools** package I maintain.  First I'll split up your `Table1$desc` into a named list using the `strsplit` function.  That's out key.  The we can do the lookup via `Table2$Desc`.  This uses the *data.table** package in the backend so it's pretty speedy:

```
library(qdapTools)

key <- setNames(strsplit(as.character(Table1[["Desc"]]), "\\s*,\\s*"), Table1[["Genes"]])

## $Apple
## [1] "Healthy" "Red"     "Fruit"  
## 
## $Candy
## [1] "Sweet"    "Cavities" "Sugar"    "Fruity"  
## 
## $Toothpaste
## [1] "Minty"   "Dentist"

Table2[["Gene"]] <- Table2[["Desc"]] %l% key

##   Col1    Desc       Gene
## 1    1   Sweet      Candy
## 2    2   Sugar      Candy
## 3    3 Dentist Toothpaste
## 4    4     Red      Apple
## 5    5   Fruit      Apple
## 6    6  Fruity      Candy
```

Here's a pure base vector lookup that should also be pretty speedy:

```
x <- strsplit(as.character(Table1[["Desc"]]), "\\s*,\\s*")
key <- setNames(rep(Table1[["Genes"]], sapply(x, length)), unlist(x))
Table2[["Gene"]] <- key[match(Table2[["Desc"]], names(key))]
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that each string is unique (i.e. that Fruit can't appear for more than one Gene), you can do this fairly easily using a `for` loop and `grep`. It may be slow on a huge dataset however.

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
Table1 <- data.frame("Random" = c("A", "B", "C"), "Genes" = c("Apple", "Candy", "Toothpaste"), "Extra" = c("Up", "", "Down"), "Desc" = c("Healthy,Red,Fruit", "Sweet,Cavities,Sugar,Fruity", "Minty,Dentist"))
Table2 <- data.frame("Col1" = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), "Desc" = c("Sweet", "Sugar", "Dentist", "Red", "Fruit", "Fruity"))

Table2$Gene <- NA
for(x in 1:nrow(Table2)) {

    Table2[x,"Gene"] <- Table1$Genes[grep(pattern = paste("\\b",Table2$Desc[x],"\\b",sep=""),x = Table1$Desc)]
}
Table2

  Col1    Desc       Gene
1    1   Sweet      Candy
2    2   Sugar      Candy
3    3 Dentist Toothpaste
4    4     Red      Apple
5    5   Fruit      Apple
6    6  Fruity      Candy
```

Answer (score 3):

Following @TylerRinker's answer, I'd format the `Table1$Desc` string first:

```
Table1a        <- with(Table1,
                    stack(setNames(sapply(as.character(Desc),strsplit,split=","),Genes)))
names(Table1a) <- c("Desc","Genes")
```

Then go to `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
DT1 <- data.table(Table1a,key="Desc")
DT2 <- data.table(Table2,key="Desc")
```

Then merge-n-define:

```
DT2[DT1,Gene:=Genes]
#    Col1    Desc       Gene
# 1:    3 Dentist Toothpaste
# 2:    5   Fruit      Apple
# 3:    6  Fruity      Candy
# 4:    4     Red      Apple
# 5:    2   Sugar      Candy
# 6:    1   Sweet      Candy
```

Comment: This is precisely what `%l%` in **qdapTools** is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there aren't too many terms to match, here's an option using some `tidyverse` functions:

```
library(tidyverse)
crossing(Table1, Table2) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(str_detect(Desc, Desc1)) %>% 
  select(Col1, Desc = Desc1, Genes) %>% 
  arrange(Col1)

# A tibble: 7 x 3
   Col1 Desc    Genes     
  <dbl> <chr>   <chr>     
1     1 Sweet   Candy     
2     2 Sugar   Candy     
3     3 Dentist Toothpaste
4     4 Red     Apple     
5     5 Fruit   Apple     
6     5 Fruit   Candy     
7     6 Fruity  Candy
```